# Authentication_failure docker and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, .net-core

I'm unable to connect to PostgreSQL that is hosted in docker through my .Net core application. I'm, however able to connect to my PostgreSQL database through PgAdmin 4 that is also hosted through Docker.

**Compose file**

```
  discountdb:
    container_name: discountdb
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin1234
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: Discountdb
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes: 
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@aspnetrun.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin1234
    ports: 
      - 505:80
    volumes:
       - pgadmin_data:/root/.pgadmin
```

**ConnectionString**

```
"ConnectionString": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
```

**NpgsqlConnection**

```
 using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(this._config.GetValue<string>("DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString")))
```

**Error**

```
password authentication failed for user admin
```

I have to repeat myself: I'm able to connect to PostgreSQL through pgAdmin 4 with user: admin and password: admin1234

Any idea, what can cause that a .net core application cannot authenticate?

Comment: Shouldn't the connection string be: `"Host=discountdb;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"`?

Comment: Depends, I'm hosting PostgreSQL on docker but my console application on localhost. Theoretically, I should be able to connect to my docker through localhost. But something with the authentication goes wrong.